# Proof of sequential composition for approximate differential privacy

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, differential

I'm trying to prove sequential composition of two (or more) approximate differentially private mechanisms.

The only reference I can find is `[here]` `[1]`, bottom of page 491, top of 492. In particular, I think the presented proof has problem, namely when she says:

> If we look at the additive contribution of each of the $\delta$ terms, of
> which there are T [2 in my example above], we notice that they are
> only every multiplied by probabilities, which are at most 1.

The problem is the $\delta$ are multiplied by $\exp(\epsilon) P(x_i )$, which can be arbitrarily large. Note, there is also a term $\delta^k$ she seems to be ignoring. This again can be large.

**Question 1:** What am I misunderstanding with this proof?

I've tried to prove this myself, but come up short. Here's an attempt at a proof:

Let $\chi$ be our universe of datasets, and let $X$, $X' \in \chi$ be two neighboring datasets. I'll try the proof for two mechanisms that are sequential, so the second can depend on the first's output. So let
$F: \chi \to \mathbb{R}$ be an $(\epsilon, \delta)$-DP mechanism and let
$G: \mathbb{R}\times\chi \to \mathbb{R}$ with $G(r, \cdot)$ $(\epsilon, \delta)$-DP mechanism for any $r\in \mathbb{R}$.

Our goal is to show that $H(X):= [ F(X), G( F(X), X) ] \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is $(2\epsilon, 2\delta)$-DP.

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be measurable. Let $A_1 = $Proj$_1 (A)$. Let $A_r = \{s: (r,s ) \in A\}$.

\begin{align} 
P(H(X)\in A) &= \int_{A_1} p_{F(X)}(r) P(G(r,X)\in A_r) dr \\
  & \leq   \int_{A_1} p_{F(X)}(r) [e^\epsilon P(G(r,X')\in A_r) + \delta dr \\
  & =  e^\epsilon \int_{A_1} p_{F(X)}(r)P(G(r,X')\in A_r) dr + \delta\int_{A_1} p_{F(X)}(r) dr\\
  & = e^\epsilon P([ F(X), G(F(X), X')] \in A) + \delta P(F(X) \in A_1)
\end{align}
Now we apply the same trick to the $P([ F(X), G(F(X), X')] \in A) $ but swap F and G (so we integrate over $s\in A_2 = $Proj$_2(A)$ against G's density $p_{G(F(X),X')}(s)$ times $P(F(X)\in A_s)$.
We obtain:

\begin{align} 
P(H(X)\in A) &\leq  e^\epsilon [ e^\epsilon P(H(X') \in A) + P( G( F(X), F(X')) \in A_2 )\delta] +  P(F(X) \in A_1) \delta\\
  & = e^{2\epsilon} P(H(X') \in A) + e^{\epsilon} P( G( F(X), F(X')) \in A_2 )\delta + P(F(X) \in A_1) \delta
\end{align}

The first term ($e^{2\epsilon} P(H(X') \in A)$) is what we want!

The last term, $P(F(X) \in A_1) \delta \leq \delta$, so that is what we want!

The middle term has the same problem the cited paper has, $e^{\epsilon} P( G( F(X), F(X')) \in A_2 )\delta \leq e^{\epsilon}\delta$, but that may be huge (if we can bound it above by $\delta$ we have the result.

**Question 2:** How do we fix this proof?

*Dwork, Cynthia; Kenthapadi, Krishnaram; McSherry, Frank; Mironov, Ilya; Naor, Moni*, [**Our data, ourselves: privacy via distributed noise generation**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/11761679_29), Vaudenay, Serge (ed.), Advances in cryptology – EUROCRYPT 2006. 25th annual international conference on the theory and applications of cryptographic techniques, St. Petersburg, Russia, May 28 – June 1, 2006. Proceedings. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 3-540-34546-9/pbk). Lecture Notes in Computer Science 4004, 486-503 (2006). [ZBL1140.94336](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1140.94336).
[1]: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/11761679.pdf?pdf=button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to Q1: See related post [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/81026/proof-of-the-basic-differential-privacy-composition-theorem?newreg=28d7b0485ec84dcdb049a9e9ac674093), which identifies the same problems with the proof cited in the question.

Answer to Q2: Using notation like above, but simplified: $F = F(X), G_r = G(r,X), F' = F(X'),$ etc.

\begin{align} 
P[H\in A] &= P[F \in A_1] P[ (x,G_x)\in A | F = x]\\
 & = P[F \in A_1] P[ G_x \in A_x | x]\\
 &\leq P[F \in A_1] ( \min\{ 1, P[G_x' \in A_x|x]e^{\epsilon_2}\} +\delta_2)\\
&\leq P[F \in A_1]  \min\{ 1, P[G_x' \in A_x|x]e^{\epsilon_2}\} +\delta_2 \phantom{aaaaaaa} \text{ since $P[F \in A_1] \leq 1$} \\
&\leq (P[F' \in A_1]e^{\epsilon_1} + \delta_1)  \min\{ 1, P[G_x' \in A_x|x]e^{\epsilon_2}\} +\delta_2\\
&\leq P[F' \in A_1]P[G_x' \in A_x|x]e^{\epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2} + \delta_1 + \delta_2\\
&= P(H' \in A) e^{\epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2} + \delta_1 + \delta_2
\end{align}